# How to allow automatic download files for Chrome with Selenium in Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

```
   I need to automatically download file to avoid browser pop up because there is no good way to handle this with Selenium
```

I want that file (json) will be automatically download without any pop up browser which shows where file will be downloaded and has 2 buttons "Save" and "Cancel".

I tried this settings, but it doesn't work

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("-js-flags=--expose-gc");
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
    options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");
 
    Map<String, Object> pref = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    pref.put("download.default_directory", getDownloadDir());
    pref.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
    pref.put("download.extensions_to_open", "application/json");
    pref.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 1);
    pref.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
    pref.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 0);
    pref.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
       
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", pref);
```

Can you help me, please? I don't have any ideas how to do this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below argument to the existing list:

`options.addArguments("--disable-features=DownloadBubble,DownloadBubbleV2");`

This will disable the download popup for all the cases when using chrome/chromium based browsers.

Your options should look like :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("-js-flags=--expose-gc");
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");
options.addArguments("--disable-features=DownloadBubble,DownloadBubbleV2"); <-- New addition
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but it didn't help with k8s env. Forgot to mention, I am running tests on the Grid

Comment: In that case, have you set the file detector for the remote webdriver?

`driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector())`

Comment: We're running our tests in k8s grid as well. And the above fields help with the downloads.

Comment: You are right. We are not setting FileDetector for remote webdriver. Truly, I don't understand how it helps with downloading files. When test downloads file, it stores on the grid server, and it's ok for us.